# queuing ajax requests with ajaxQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue

i want to use the jquery plugin ajaxQ. The documentation says that all necessary stuff to extend is to write this

```
$.ajaxq("myqueue", { ... })
```

instead of

```
$.ajax ({ ... })
```

But it seems to still fire the requests at the same time. Does anybody knows if i am missing here something.

Comment: Impossible to say if we don't know how you are using it. If you really just change your calls to `$.ajaxq("myqueue",...)`, then it should work according to the documentation.

Comment: everything i did is including the plugin and change my ajax-Request like i wrote above. And i also dont know really how to debug this ...
i can in debug only see that the queue is filled. Maybe i have to overwrite some default configurations that is actually send the requests after each other ?

Comment: Are you talking about http://foliotek.github.com/AjaxQ/?  The demos on that page are using the following code: https://github.com/Foliotek/AjaxQ/blob/master/demo/demo.js#L51.  Can you put together a demo on jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: sry for this question, i just had some problems with my debugging my code works ...